# Copy - paste values while creating growing List

Tags: vba, excel

I want to have a macro which runs everytime I open the excel-file, then compares the date (I5) with the last entry in a list (column L), and if the date is older, copy some values (I5 and I11) and paste them in the next empty row of the list (columns L and M). I have written the code bellow but it does not work, I get runtime error 424 and every other syntax I found online and tried to adapt isn't working either. Can anyone help ?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

If Worksheets("overdue").Range("I5").Value > Worksheets("overdue").Range("L2").End(xlDown).Value Then  
Worksheets("overdue").Range("I5").Copy  
Worksheets("overdue").Range("L1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Worksheets("overdue").Range("I11").Copy    
Worksheets("overdue").Range("M1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If columns L or M are blank you are trying to paste in the row after the last row in the spreadsheet.

Comment: That was the error. I addes some random values in L and M and it worked nicely, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below, in case you have only 1 row in column "L" (I guess header):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim LastRow As Long

With Worksheets("overdue")
    LastRow = .Range("L1").End(xlDown).Row

    If LastRow >= 2 Then
        If .Range("I5").Value > .Range("L" & LastRow).Value Then
            .Range("L" & LastRow + 1).Value = .Range("I5").Value
            .Range("M" & LastRow + 1).Value = .Range("I11").Value
        End If
    End If
End With

End Sub
```